# How can I create a mysql connection pool using asadmin tool in GlassFish server?

Tags: mysql, glassfish

I am trying to use the following command to create a mysql connection pool in GlassFish but it keeps telling me Command `create-jdbc-connection-pool` failed.
Please help me.
The command:

```
asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool \
--datasourceclassname com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource \
--restype javax.sql.DataSource \
--property "User=root:Password=...:URL=jdbc\:mysql\:\/\/localhost:3306\/wcms_3" \
connection_pool
```

I guess that there is a missing required parameter; so what are the required parameters needed if my guess was true?

Comment: Is there any related information in the server.log file?

Comment: here is a thread for a GUI admin based jdbc connection pool <a href="http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/12/set-up-jdbc-connection-pool-glassfish-v3.html">glassfish jdbc connection pool</a>

Comment: You didn't escape the colon at "localhost:3306"

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's a typo but referring to [this blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/JagadishPrasath/entry/creating_jdbc_connection_pool_resource) only the URL-part of the `--property` has to be surrounded by double quotes, such as:

```
asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool
        --datasourceclassname oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource 
        --restype javax.sql.DataSource 
        --property user=dbuser:password=dbpassword:url="jdbc\\:oracle\\:thin\\:@localhost\\:1521\\:ORCL" oracle-pool
```

Furthermore notice the use of escape characters in this example.

Comment: following suggested format did the job for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_9_using_jdbc_connection):

- he uses the pooled datasource (which IMO is necessary)
- check the escaping of the --property string.

Alternatively, to circumvent escaping woes have a look [here](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-create-jdbc-connection-pool-and.html):

```
 --property user=root:password=test:DatabaseName=test:ServerName=localhost:port=3306
```

ie, specify the connection without using a JDBC URL.

Answer (score 0):

use following command for mysql connection pool using asadmin utility glassfish

**[glassfish installation dir]/bin/asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool --datasourceclassname com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource --restype javax.sql.DataSource --property User=[db_username]:Port=3306:Password=[db_password]:Url="jdbc:mysql://[localhost or ip]:3306/[db_name]" [pool_name]**

db_username is your database username

db_password is your database password

db_name is database name

pool_name is anything that you want

example

./asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool --datasourceclassname com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource --restype javax.sql.DataSource --property User=admin:Port=3306:Password=admin:Url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/\test" test_pool

Answer (score 0):

Following two things has solved the same issue for me. They are:

1) use <kbd>\</kbd> only for glassfish escape characters

2) try giving the command in a single line, for example

```
create-jdbc-connection-pool --datasourceclassname=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource --restype=javax.sql.DataSource --property portNumber=1527:password=APP:user=APP:serverName=localhost:databaseName=sun-appserv-samples:connectionAttributes=\;create\\=true SamplePool
```